# How to access the section index in viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind ?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

For my UICollectionView, I made a header like this :

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "B3header", forIndexPath: indexPath)

view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: headerImage)!)

return view

}
```

Now the thing is, I want to change headerImage regarding the section number, something like that :

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "headerImage\(section)")!)
```

I was able to access that index with numberOfItemsInSection and I'm wondering how I can access that value for dynamically change the background of my header.

Or maybe there's another way around ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Section index would be
`indexPath.section`